# How do I integrate with a multitenant setup?

Tags: docusignapi, multi-tenant

I'm working on a CRM product that 70 companies use. It is a multi-tenant setup. We're currently integrating DocuSign into the product. Our important requirement is that each of the 70 companies should be able to send documents for signature from the CRM, and the audit trail should show the corresponding company as the document owner. The challenge here is that we need to achieve this without onboarding all 70 companies to DocuSign. How to do this? What kind of OAuth setup will help us achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each company that sends signing requests (either directly or via your service) needs their own account.

Either:

- Each company has their own account with DocuSign
- Or your company (the ISV) provisions the 70 accounts, one per company.

For the latter, you'd join the DocuSign ISV-L program so you can provision the accounts.

But either way, each company will need their own account.

The easier method is the first one. I'd bet that many of your companies already have a DocuSign account. Your system just needs to offer DocuSign OAuth Authorization Code grant to your customers (the companies). Your software can then send on behalf of the customers.

The "on-boarding" to your account is simple for your customers, they just login with their DocuSign credentials and grant consent to your software the first time they do so.

From the companies' point of view, they just need to purchase a DocuSign account if they don't already have one. That's an easy task.

This is how most of our ISV partners work.

Comment: Thanks, Larry. Out of 70, only three have DocuSign accounts. I think the ISV route would work for us. But if we want to explore the first option and ask our users to signup for DocuSign, will they have to be on a paid plan? And how could I integrate it in a way that we'd be the ones billed for their transactions?

Comment: Yes, a paid plan is required to use DocuSign for legally binding agreements. But the signers do **not** need a paid plan. Signers usually don't need any DocuSign plan. Only the sender of a signing request (an envelope) needs a plan. If the ISV wants to be billed for the customers' plans, an ISV-L agreement is needed.

Answer (score 0):

> The challenge here is that we need to achieve this without onboarding
> all 70 companies to DocuSign

This means that you don't want them to have a DocuSign account, I assume, but you still want to

> send documents for signature from the CRM, and the audit trail should
> show the corresponding company as the document owner

You cannot do that. As these two things cotradict.

If you have a single account, it will show the name of the company/owner and that will be fixed across all 70 companies.

You can use a single organization that has multiple accounts for example. That ties the accounts together. But you do need some logical separation of these companies as far as DocuSign is concerned or else they'll all look the same at the signature level.

Comment: "You can use a single organization with multiple accounts for example." - But isn't an organization account usually for a single company and their teams? Is this an ideal use for my setup? What if I have 7000 customers instead? Any max limit for how many companies I can create under an organization account?

Comment: I agree, this doesn't fit your need, there's no maximum, but yes, the organization concept is meant for ... organizations, if your customers are not related to eachother, they just would have to have separate accounts

Answer (score 0):

To use DocuSign for your organization, you can create a single account and set it up to manage multiple tenants. For each tenant, you can create a group and assign a tenant ID as its name. Then, create a user for each tenant and add them to their respective group.

To get started, log in to DocuSign with your organization credentials. Once logged in, you can fetch the group for a specific tenant using the tenant ID and the group API. Next, fetch the user from that group and sign in to DocuSign using their credentials to obtain a JWT token.

With the token, you can now use the DocuSign envelope API to create and send an envelope. However, make sure that the users you create for each tenant have the necessary permissions to create and send envelopes on behalf of the tenant, by granting them envelope creation access to the default user of your organization.